# how to protect my steganographic image embedded in pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I used image steganography by embedding a encrypted text into an image and embedding that steganographic image (INVISIBLE watermark) into pdf for protecting PDF. This invisible watermark could be easily removed by www.pdfwatermarkremover.com . Tried to encrypt the image and embedded into PDF, but that imposes an ERROR while viewing the PDF using adobe reader. How to put invisible watermark which is invisible to pdfwatermarkremover? Please advise the suitable techniques using java for protecting and hiding sensitive data into PDF.

Here are two links shared :

//This link contains PDF embedded with image steg2.jpg which displays an ERROR while viewed with any acrobat reader

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ly6thfr6p1cd4v/Albeniz_Tango_Piano.pdf?dl=0

//Encrypted Image which is embedded to the above PDF file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qd3m4vkdn7pxg93/steg2.jpg?dl=0

[image]

Regards

Kris

Comment: Essentially everything you put into a PDF, someone else can remove again. You can try to be creative and find new variants but those also eventually will be automatically removable.

Comment: I don't want 100% foolproof solution, I need only the steganographic image should not be removed in pdf using any pdf  watermark remover only.

Comment: Why put the data into an image at all, why display the encrypted text at all? You could simply put your encrypted text into a comment in the content stream or into an otherwise unused resource of the page in question.

Comment: Thanks very much, will try and share with you.

Comment: I referred to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848053/pdfbox-make-text-invisible that makes text invisible but the text SEARCHABLE. Pls help

Comment: Making text *invisible but SEARCHABLE* is not a *suitable technique for protecting and hiding sensitive data into PDF*. Something searchable is not well hidden, is it? Furthermore you talked about images before while you now refer to text. Thus, please clarify what you really are after.

Comment: I wanted the embedded image in pdf should not be REMOVED by pdf watermark removers. That's all I required. Please help

Comment: Watermark removers improve. As soon as some new way to embed images their users want removed comes up, they'll improve to also remove those.

Comment: pls see this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ly6thfr6p1cd4v/Albeniz_Tango_Piano.pdf?dl=0 please lemme know why this pdf gives an ERROR when viewed with acrobat reader. regards, kris